# using openpop.dll to connect to Gmail in C# Service

Tags: c#, service, openpop

I am attempting to use the openpop.dll to pull email from gmail account. but I get the following error

> Problem logging in using method Auto. Server response was: `-ERR [AUTH] Username and password not accepted`. Exception thrown:
> '`OpenPop.Pop3.Exceptions.InvalidLoginException`' in `OpenPop.dll`

I rechecked my User and Password are correct (i can login from the gmail web interface).

In the `app.config`:

```
<add key="SmtpHost" value="pop.gmail.com"/>
<add key="SmtpPort" value="995"/>
```

My code:

```
client.Connect(Host, Port, true); //UseSSL true or false
LoggerService.Info("Service authentication starts.");
client.Authenticate(Email, Password);
```

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I seem to remember that Gmail may no longer supports SMTP access using the account password - I think you have to generate a specific application password for it to use.

Answer (score 2):

1.Sign into the Gmail account first, and make sure POP is enabled in settings either for ALL MAIL or only for mail that arrives from now on - depending on what you want collected.

2.Google accounts will only allow POP3 access if you have enabled the "less secure apps" feature. This can be done from this link: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Let me know if this helpful for you.

Comment: I added one more step.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please mark as accepted.

Comment: Yes, 'less secure apps' did the thing.